# paste with delphi in ole automation

Tags: delphi, automation, ms-word, ole

i want paste in delphi from richedit to word application
i used Following code but Twice paste data in word (duplicate)

```
  WordApp := GetActiveOleObject('Word.Application');
  WordApp.Visible := True;
  Wordapp.documents.open('C:\Doc1.docx');
  Richedit.Text := 'test text';
  Richedit.SelectAll;
  Richedit.CopyToClipboard;
  WordApp.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.Paste;
  WordApp.selection.paste;
```

Answer (score 7):

Try leaving out the last line of your code

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to end up with this?

```
test text
test text
```

But only getting this?

```
test text
```

If so, then maybe the "selection" is causing it to paste the same data into the same selection, thus the 2nd paste wipes out the first one.